# Flutter IOS app build error after added firebase crashlytics

Tags: flutter, crashlytics, codemagic

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building  for device (ios-release)...
Running pod install...
124.8s (!)
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                           com.example.app                11.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Encountered error while building for device.
Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS

Comment: Try going through these instructions once more https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics#ios-integration